# Newtonsoft Jtokne tostring converting when device language is not english

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android, json.net

I want to parse a json block like this in my monodroid application:

```
 bubbles    {{
  "count": 4,
  "lat": 42.78875,
  "lng": -90.255,
  "bubble_icon": "m1.png"
}}
```

I'm using this code:

```
string s= bubbles ["lat"].ToString ()
```

When I using english language in my device it is working right. but by other language it is not working good. For example some times, it replace '.' with ',' and some time do not iclude some numbers.

I have a problem like this with `Double.Parse()` and resolve it with `CultureInfo` but it seems that it is not working for JToken

Comment: Do any body have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public static double JtokeToDoubel(JToken token){
        try {
            if(token .Type == JTokenType .String ){
                return RltParseDouble ((string) token );
            }
            return (double )token;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            RltLog .HandleException (ex);
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```